# Join all non-empty cells in row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here is an example version of a Sheet I have:

[image]

The first column (A) is where the function I hope to create will go. I need a formula that joins *all* the cells in the row but skips the cells that are empty. The image above shows the desired outcome. If I use `JOIN()` it will put a blank space in for each empty cell, so `JOIN(", ",A2:D2)` would give me `Jade, ,Mariela`, but I don't want that blank spot in there.

Is there a function to do this?
TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `TEXTJOIN()` instead `JOIN()` with ignore empty option TRUE.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,B2:I2)
```

Answer (score 0):

delete everything in A column and use in A2:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(B2:I="",,B2:I&",")),,9^9))), ",$", ))
```